# CSS min-height and border

Tags: css

I have this page layout:

```
<header> 
<content> 
<footer>
```

I have border-left and right applied to content, with min-height. BUT if the content is more than the min-height then the borders don't re-adjust accordingly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you try so far? give your code and explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some floating elements inside your content block, so the content block is not adjusting because of lack of 'real' content. Try adding something like `<br style="clear: both;" />` inside your content block after the rest of what's inside it.
Or else, and perhaps even better, explain your problem with making a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

kasimir is right it is probably a clearing issue, if you are using floats, i prefer the the clearfix approach (although some foolery is needed in older versions of IE) as it is more semantically correct (i think).

http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

An update with a bit of code would be useful.

Comment: I agree adding the `<br />` is a 'quick-and-dirty' method. I use it to establish where a clearfix is required. Stackoverflow being such a superb resource, already contains an excellent discussion about the best or correct method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best

Comment: @kasimir i should have added this as a comment not an answer as yours was correct, need to learn how to use this site properly!